# How does, "select for update" work using vbscript?

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to write a simple script that will query the database and retrieve a piece of information from the database.  I'll then do something with that information and then update it's record with some sort of a result.  I'll have 10 threads running doing the same thing.  I want to make sure that another thread doesn't select an already selected row.

My question is how do I do this in vbscript?  I can run queries and updates no problem but is there something special I have to do to lock the row, do some work, update the record and commit?

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar process running with a SQL Server table, updated by multiple workstations all running the same code on the same data (work queue).  To ensure they don't trip over each other, I have a column called Workstation in the table.  When a workstation retrieves a record it retrieves the first that has a Workstation value of null, and updates the column to be the Workstation name.

This prevents any other retrieval query from picking up data from the work queue that "belongs to" another workstation.  I have the "allocation" routine picking up 10 records per workstation at a time so there's work being done and the chances of crossover between machines requesting at the same time is reduced (in point of fact it's never happened).